# How to handle raw-post-data in Hunchentoot

Tags: json, common-lisp, ccl, hunchentoot

I'm working on a Lisp API utilizing RESTAS, Hunchentoot and CL-JSON. I have a route defined like this:

```
(define-route user/register ("/user/register" :method :post)
  (let* ((raw-data (hunchentoot:raw-post-data :force-text t))
     (params (json:decode-json-from-string)))
    (format t "List of parameters: ~a~%" params)
      ))
```

Now I'm using Postman to send HTTP POST requests with some example JSON data in the request body that looks like this:

```
{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "login": "jdoe",
    "password": "lalala",
    "email": "jdoe@ietf.org",
    "organization": "IETF"
}
```

The request body clearly gets through, as I'm able to output it to the screen, but the `decode-json` part leaves me with a 500 server error. I've tried some combinations that seemed reasonable, but I was unable to parse that JSON. Ideally I'd like to parse it to a `plist`, `alist` or a hash table. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you actually want to decode? You might want to tell Lisp about that.

Comment: To add further clarity to @RainerJoswig's comment, in case anyone else stumbles across this old relic, it looks like your original code was calling `json:decode-json-from-string` without any arguments, and that was presumably the problem.  I presume you've long since fixed it, by utilizing the debugging options from the accepted answer, but thought I'd point this out for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (restas:debug-mode-on) for debugging.

Comment: Thanks, @archimag. It turns out I actually already had an alist in `params` only didn't know it. A `(break)` in the route definition also helped investigating `params`.